# How do I automate my robot with java

Tags: java, methods, automation, while-loop, call

How do I automate my robot

I have a robot that is being controlled by key presses, if the key pressed equals a certain key, either up, down, left or right are registered and the robot will move. I also have the following methods to play around with:

- int getSpeed();
- void forwardGear();
- void reverseGear();
  isTouchingWall(); Booleon

I basically want to say if speed equals 0 than I can shift up a gear and then accelerate.
And if the robot isTouchingWall() turn around or something.
I'm not sure how I can use the reverseGear() method yet.

This is my code so far:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case 37:  
                    super.turnLeft();
                    break;
                case 38:  
                    super.accelerate();
                    break;
                case 39:  
                    super.turnRight(); 
                break;
                case 40: 
                    super.decelerate();
                    break;
        }

}
```

Comment: Magic number alert!

Comment: Fredley means that it's bad form to hardcode a number in you code. You should create a constant so that the number has a name and then use the names in your case statement.

Comment: So, I'm not sure what you're asking. How to actually communicate with the Robot? If so, there's not nearly enough information here. Does the robot have a USB port? Who made it? What is the API for the robot?

Comment: You can use another key for reversegear().

Comment: Yeah sorry the robot does have an api. It can be located here: http://x2.i-dat.org/simon/RoboDomeDocs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another Key for reverseGear() for example 'r'

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case 37:  
                    super.turnLeft();
                    break;
                case 38:  
                    super.accelerate();
                    break;
                case 39:  
                    super.turnRight(); 
                break;
                case 40: 
                    super.decelerate();
                    break;
                case 82: 
                    super.reverseGear();//key r
                    break;

        }

}
```